# Could not extract .bin file

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk, openjdk

I can not extract `.bin` file on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
Error message:

```
root@ilgar-Ubuntu:~# '/home/ilgar/jre-6u21-linux-i586.bin' 
Unpacking...
Checksumming...
Extracting...
/home/ilgar/jre-6u21-linux-i586.bin: 86: /home/ilgar/jre-6u21-linux-i586.bin: ./install.sfx.10336: not found
Failed to extract the files.  Please refer to the Troubleshooting section of
the Installation Instructions on the download page for more information.
```

Open JDK is installed:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_91"
```

Comment: It's not recommended to install java with this binary installer anyway. It's preferred to install it from the [repository](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu) or, if you must have the orcale-java, install it from a ppa: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/09/install-oracle-java-8-in-ubuntu-via-ppa.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be because you are using an x64 system. If you are, install the 32 bit libs with:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Then try to run the self extraction file again.

Hope that helps.